# Синхронизировать объекты на клиенте и сервере, в Unet?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Сделал мультиплеер посредством Unet

На сцене есть объект (маска которую можно надеть на персонажа), сам скрипт работает корректно , что у первого что у второго игрока, но вот синхронизация оставляет желать лучшего.

Когда я на хосте (сервере, создателе сервера, как угодно) надеваю маску на своего персонажа, она нормально одевается и снимается тоже, если смотреть на это дело со стороны клиента (подключившего игрока), то прекрасно видно как он снимает и надевает его

весь код скрипта :

```
public class ForMask : NetworkBehaviour
{

    public Transform Formask;

    public Transform Formask2;
    public Transform Drop;
    public bool OnMe = false;
    public bool Resolution = false;
    public bool OnMe2 = false;
    public bool Resolution2 = false;

    float rotationX = 0;
    public float lookSpeed = 2.0f;
    public float lookXLimit = 45.0f;
    public Transform mask;
    public bool TextOver = false;
    public Text MyTestLabel;

    


    // Start is called before the first frame update

    void Start()
    {
        //Formask = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Formask").transform;
        //Formask2 = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Formask2").transform;
       //Drop = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Drop").transform;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
  



    void Update()
    {
        CmdTextOverObject();
       //Formask = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Formask").transform;
       //Formask2 = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Formask2").transform;
       //Drop = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Drop").transform;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0) && Resolution) //если нажали на лкм и игрок рядом то надеваем на него
       {
         Formask = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Formask").transform;

         GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = false;
         GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false;
         transform.position = Formask.position;
         OnMe = true;
       }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0) && Resolution2)
        {
            Formask2 = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Formask2").transform;

            GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = false;
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false;
            transform.position = Formask2.position;
            OnMe2 = true;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse1) && Resolution)
       {
            Drop = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Drop").transform;

            OnMe = false;
            transform.position = Drop.position;
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = true;
            GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = true;
        }
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse1) && Resolution2)
        {
            Drop = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Drop").transform;

            OnMe2 = false;
            transform.position = Drop.position;
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = true;
            GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = true;
        }

        if (OnMe)
      {
       transform.position = Formask.position;

           
            transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * lookSpeed, 0);
        }
        if (OnMe2)
        {
            transform.position = Formask2.position;
            transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * lookSpeed, 0);
        }

    }

  


    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col) //проверяем приблизился ли игрок
    {
      if(col.gameObject.tag == "Player")
      {
        Resolution = true;
      }
        else if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player2")
        {
            Resolution2 = true;
        }
    }

    
    void OnTriggerExit(Collider col)
    {
      if(col.gameObject.tag == "Player")
      {
        Resolution = false;
      }
       else if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player2")
        {
            Resolution2 = false;
        }
    }
```

Но вот со стороны клиента, когда я ее надеваю, на хосте этого не видно.

по сути я надел маску, на клиенте это видно, а у хоста она все так же продолжает лежать на столе.

Полистал в интернете насчет этого, но исчерпывающего ответа так и не нашел, везде лишь речь про синхронизацию игроков. Мне стало интересно почему же когда сервер что-то делает, то это видит клиент,а вот в обратном порядке синхронизации просто никакой.

(я настроил все что нужно, сами игроки двигаются правильно и плавно, но вот взаймодействие хромает причем на обе ноги)

В чем вопрос, как мне от лица клиента, дать хосту понять что я изменил положение этой "маски", когда надел, и то что я изменил его обратно, когда снял?

(дело не в маске, не так принципиально, оно ни каких объектах толком нормально не пашет)

знаю что код костыльный, но мне в данный момент важна его работоспособность, а не чистота

Comment: Нужно видеть код, примеры скриптов того, о чем вы пишете.

Comment: дополнил вопрос, код в нем

Answer (score 0):

через

```
[Commаnd]
```

public void Primer()
{
*действие для второго игрока*
}

добился того чего надо

все что делает клиент сервер видит, клиент тоже видит что делает сервер

как оказалось, мне проще из клиента сделать "попрошайку" нежели копаться с этим

[ClientRPC]

, когда надо клиент просто просит , а сервер от себя это делает, а не от лица клиента

как писали на большинстве сайтов.

насколько я понял, от лица клиента он может что-то сделать как раз таки в этом

[ClientRPC]

, но мне нет дела до этого, поскольку оно работает, хоть как-то

и да, объясню ситуацию и дам пример кода (я же не тот злой дядька с англояз сайта, что лишь что-то втирает про АссигнЛокалАуторити, а пример рабочего кода не дает)

итак! если хотите чтоб клиент делал что-либо, и это видел сервер тоже

просто сделайте так:

1. - напишите метод комманд
2. - вызовите его когда нужно (при нажатии клавиши там или просто в апдейте)
3. - смотрите как оно работает в обе стороны

сам пример кода :
[image: пример]